# *.JT CAD format direct import

Tags: python, add-on, import, file-format, conversion

1. Has anyone stumbled across a decent way of importing .jt CAD files into Blender? Direct import would be nice.
2. Currently I am using CAD Exchanger (paid license) but if someone is using an different  app (preferably free/ open source) to do a conversion, I would love to hear about it.

Thanks!

Comment: just wanted to express I am looking also for a soluition to import JT files to blender.